# Google Calendar API ServiceAccountCredential

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use Google's Calendar API.  I pretty much used the exact code from their [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) page.  Instead of using the UserCredential object, I would like to use the ServiceAccountCredential object so I can authenticate with my service account.  The code works fine when I authenticate with the UserCredential object, but I don't want to rely on my users having a Google account.  When I try to authenticate with the ServiceAccountCredential object, I do not get any results from the Calendar.  I also do not get any error either, just no results.  Below is my method for getting my ServiceAccountCredential.  Does anyone know what I am missing?

```
        private ServiceAccountCredential GetServiceAccountCredential()
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = null;

        string[] scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        using (var stream = EmbededResourceHelper.ExtractResourceAsStream("<<downloaded json file>>.json"))
        {
            var credentialParameters = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<JsonCredentialParameters>(stream);
            if (credentialParameters.Type != "service_account"
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentialParameters.ClientEmail)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentialParameters.PrivateKey))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("JSON data does not represent a valid service account credential.");
            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credentialParameters.ClientEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes,
                }.FromPrivateKey(credentialParameters.PrivateKey)
            );
        }
        return credential;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which calendar are you trying to access? I'd expect a service account to only have access to completely public calendars by default. (I don't know whether there's some way to give a service account its own calendar... that sounds like something that *may* be feasible if that's useful, but we don't know much about what you're trying to achieve.) Also, is there any reason you're extracting the JSON yourself rather than using `GoogleCredential.FromStream`?

Comment: I have my own google account and the google calendar is under this account.  I created a service account in the Google Developer Console under my account.  So I am trying to get this service account to be able to update my calendar.  I have also tried using GoogleCredential.FromStream and I got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to share your personal calendar with your service account. To do so, go to your calendar's settings, and under "Share with specific people", put your service account's email (e.g. myserviceaccount@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com)